# jQuery AJAX Success Callback is not Working for JSON data type

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get some JSON data from `ajax_autocomplete.php` then do something in the success callback. The problem is that I can't get into success callback, neither the error callback says anything.

I checked my JSON and it's valid, I've been trying for two hours now and can't find the solution.

```
$("#reg").autocomplete({
  minLength: 2,
  dataType: 'json',
  source: 'ajax_autocomplete.php',
  success : function(data){
    alert('success');
  },
  error : function(xhr, status){
    console.log(status);
  }
```

});

Here is my JSON:

```
[{"label":"Test id 1","id":"1"},{"label":"Test id 2","id":"2"}]
```

I tried adding

```
type: 'GET',
async : false,
```

But it isn't working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be trying to follow the documentation for `jQuery.ajax` instead of `jQuery.autocomplete`, most of those options don't appear to me mentioned [in the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#reg" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_autocomplete.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                  return {
                    label: item.label,
                    value: item.id
                  }
                }));
                // do something
            }
        });
    },

    select: function( event, ui ) {
        // ...
    },
    open: function() {
        // ...
    },
    close: function() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.ajax({
                url : "ajax_autocomplete.php",
                data : {},
                type : "GET",
                success : function(data) {
                          alert(data);
                },
                error : function(err) {
                             alert(err);
                }                       
    });
```